# How to have a default "please select" option on an Angular select element with a null value for validation?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a select HTML element in an Angular ngFor loop:

```
<select formControlName="type" required>
  <option *ngFor="let type of typeList" [ngValue]="type.value">{{ type.caption }}</option>
</select>
```

In Internet Explorer, the first item in the list is selected when the template loads, but it's value isn't set in the form control, so causes a 'required' validation error until another value is selected in the list. I want to have a 'Please select' option that has a null value to prevent this happening.

This is for Angular 2+ used with or without TypeScript

Answer (score 5):

Add an option like so:

```
   <option [ngValue]="null">Please select</option>
```

So your control will look like:

```
<select formControlName="type" required>
  <option [ngValue]="null">Please select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let type of typeList" [ngValue]="type.value">{{ type.caption }}</option>
</select>
```

This works as Angular inspects the value attribute because of the square brackets. The value becomes a true null, unlike if we used value="" (this is just an empty string and doesn't match null).

Answer (score 0):

In case you're not using `ngForm`, another approach to implementing the selected value is to do something like `[value]='selectedType' (change)='selectedType = $event.target.value'` in your `select` tag. For example:

In your component.ts:

```
public selectedType: string;
```

In your component.html

```
<select [value]='selectedType' (change)='selectedType = $event.target.value'>
  <option value=''>-- Select your Type --</option>
  <option *ngFor="let type of typeList" [ngValue]="type.value">{{ type.caption }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

component.ts

```
public selectedValue = 'None';
```

component.html:

```
    <div ">
        <label>Highlight</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedTrunk" (change)="onChangeTrunk($event)">
                <option value='None'>None</option>
                <option *ngFor="let trunklist of DRLNameTrunkList" [selected]="trunk" [value]="trunklist.SIPTRUNKNAME">{{trunklist.SIPTRUNKNAME}}</option>
             </select>
    </div>
```

This is my code pelase modify as per your requirements